# flutter: BoxShadow errors

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-container

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    boxShadow: BoxShadow(
      color: Colors.black,
      blurRadius: 5,
      spreadRadius: 6,
    ),
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
    border: Border(
      left: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 10.0),
    ),
  ),
)
```

What is wrong, why are there red lines under the Boxshadow? I watched a video and did exactly what he did. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass list of `BoxShadow` on `boxShadow`.

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    boxShadow: [ // issue was here
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.black,
        blurRadius: 5,
        spreadRadius: 6,
      ),
    ],
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
    border: Border(
      left: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 10.0),
    ),
  ),
)
```

More about [`Container`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html)

Comment: When I get four more reputation I will confirm your answer as valid thanks again!!!